FileNotFoundError while using send_file in a Flask app
This error shows
Here is my code:
<p>
<a href="{{ url_for('views.download_csv', semester_name=semester.semester_name) }}">Download CSV File</a>
</p>

    distribution_df = pd.DataFrame(distribution_dict)
    file_name = f'{semester.semester_name}_grade_distributions_{str(datetime.now())}.csv'
    file_name = secure_filename(file_name)
    output_dir = 'output'
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir)
    path = f'{output_dir}/{file_name}'
    distribution_df.to_csv(path , index=False)
    print("Checking path:", path)
    print("Path exists:", os.path.exists(path))
    
    return send_file(path)

As you see it is clearly creating the csv files
So why does this error shows up and how can I fix it.
I tried running my code vscode in admistrator mode and also tried send_from_directory but neither worked. I want the csv file to be download when the link is clicked in my app.

Look at he full path of the file its trying to look for. In your error directories are separated by 2 backslashes (\) but the last part where in your code you are building that path you are using a single forward slash (/)

A better way to handle system paths is by using pathlib.
from pathlib import Path
output_path = Path('output') / file_name


You fix the line for your path like this: path = f'{output_dir}\\{file_name}'



Even better if they use Path.join (?)  and let pathlib handle the separators
